# PHP foreign key issues submitting new data

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a page where when a use clicks submit on a their blog post, it posts it to the preexisting database table. The error I keep getting is I'm not referencing the table id (tid) properly from the blog post to the blog table. I think if I changed the values of my radio buttons to the corresponding table id values and did some loop with them it would work but I'm still unsure how to reference it. Really stuck at this point. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here's my radio buttons to select which table to view:

first.php

```
<form name ="myForm" action ="second.php<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" method = "POST">
    <h3> Guitar Blog Topics </h3><br>
    <input type ="radio" name = "radio1" value ="Topic1" /> Topic1 <br>
    <input type ="radio" name ="radio1" value ="Topic2" /> Topic2 <br>
    <input type ="radio" name = "radio1" value ="Topic3" /> Topic3 <br>
    <input type = "submit" value = "Select"/>
</form>
```

I think my issue could be right here with hardcoding the topic names in instead of putting just the title ids (tid) as the values as 1,2,3.

At the bottom of this page in my $sql is where I'm not sure how to reference my foreign key (tid).

second.php

```
$answer = $_POST['radio1'];
$query = "SELECT * from blog_posts join blog_topics using (tid) where topic = '$answer'";
$result = mysqli_query($dbconnect, $query);
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($num_rows > 0) // build a table to show results
{
    echo "<table border='1'>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>Post ID </th>"; echo "<th>Author</th>";
    echo "<th>Title</th>"; echo "<th>Post</th>";
    echo "</tr>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['pid'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['author'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['title'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['post'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }   
    echo "</table>";
} else{
    echo "No rows returned.";
}
?>

<form name ="myForm" action ="" method = "POST"> <br><br><br>
    <h3> Create a Post </h3>
    Author  <input type ="text" size ="40" name ="author"/><br>
    Title <input type ="text" size ="30" name ="title"/><br><br>
    Post <br><textarea rows ="15" cols ="10" name ="post"></textarea><br>
    <input type ="submit" name = "submitpost" value ="Submit Post"/>
</form>
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){
if(isset($_POST['submitpost'])){

$sql = mysqli_query($dbconnect, "INSERT INTO blog_posts (pid, author,         title, post, tid)
VALUES (NULL, '$_POST[author]', '$_POST[title]', '$_POST[post]')") //THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO REFERENCE TID

or die(mysqli_error($dbconnect));

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your list of columns does not match the values list so you are trying to input something that does not exist. Try

```
$tid = 'my table id'; // if the datatype of the tid column is varchar
$tid = 3456; // if the datatype of the tid column is int
$tid = $_POST[tid];// make sure when using the $_POST variable that the value matches the  datatype      

$sql = mysqli_query($dbconnect, "INSERT INTO blog_posts (pid, author, title, post, tid) VALUES (NULL, '$_POST[author]', '$_POST[title]', '$_POST[post]', $tid)")
```

Comment: That's what I was thinking to, but with changing the values of the radio buttons to correspond to the tid value. I'm just confused on the syntax if I'd be able to do something like                                                $tid = $_POST[radio1].value;